# date_trunc in hive is working incorrectly

Tags: hive, presto

I am running below query:

```
select a.event_date,
    date_format(date_trunc('month', a.event_date), '%m/%d/%Y') as date
from monthly_test_table a
order by 1;
```

Output:

```
 2017-09-15 | 09/01/2017
 2017-10-01 | 09/30/2017
 2017-11-01 | 11/01/2017
```

Can anyone tell me why for date "2017-10-01" it is showing me date as "09/30/2017" after using date_trunc.

Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Can you include your desired format in the question, that will help to answer the question.

Comment: Can you please tell me the TimeZone?

Comment: Besides session time zone, what's the definition of `monthly_test_table` -- how it was created, how it's read. Are you using Hive or Presto?

Answer (score 0):

You are reverse formatting so it is incorrect. 
Use the below Code

```
select a.event_date,
    date_format(date_trunc('month', a.event_date), '%Y/%m/%d') as date
from monthly_test_table a
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_add` with a logic to subtract 1-day(yourdate) to replicate `trunc`.

For eg:

```
2017-10-01 - day('2017-10-01') is 1 and you add 1-1=0 days 
2017-08-30 - day('2017-08-30') is 30 and you add 1-30=-29 days
```

I faced the same issue recently and resorted to using this logic.

```
date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(event_date,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),
         1-day(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(event_date,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))
        )
```

PS: As far as i know, there  is no `date_trunc` function in [**`Hive documentation`**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions).

Answer (score 0):

As per the source code below: `UTC_CHRONOLOGY` time is translated w.r.t. locale, also in `Description` it is mentioned that session timezone will be the precision, also refer to below URL.

```
@Description("truncate to the specified precision in the session timezone")
@ScalarFunction("date_trunc")
@LiteralParameters("x")
@SqlType(StandardTypes.DATE)
public static long truncateDate(ConnectorSession session, @SqlType("varchar(x)") Slice unit, @SqlType(StandardTypes.DATE) long date)
{
    long millis = getDateField(UTC_CHRONOLOGY, unit).roundFloor(DAYS.toMillis(date));
    return MILLISECONDS.toDays(millis);
}
```

See https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.66.html:::

> Time Zones:
>   This release has full support for time zone rules, which are needed to perform date/time calculations correctly. Typically, the session time zone is used for temporal calculations. This is the time zone of the client computer that submits the query, if available. Otherwise, it is the time zone of the server running the Presto coordinator.
>
> **Queries that operate with time zones that follow daylight saving can
>   produce unexpected results.** For example, if we run the following query
>   to add 24 hours using in the America/Los Angeles time zone:
>
> SELECT date_add('hour', 24, TIMESTAMP '**2014-03-08 09:00:00**');
>
> Output: **2014-03-09 10:00:00.000**